# Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ) and Regular Boundaries one shapefile

Tags: shapefile, merge, administrative-boundaries, boundaries, africa

Does anyone have an idea if there is a shapefile of the merged EEZ boundaries and regular administrative boundaries? I need this data for entire Africa. I have downloaded the EEZ boundaries from http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php but they don't match with any of the administrative datasets that I have located that show the African continent boundaries. There are gaps and overlaps. I can do merge or similar but since it is for an entire continent, it would take a lot of time? I am surprised not being able to find the merged boundaries online. Any ideas?

[image: Green is the continental boundary from ESRI and orange/brown is the EEZ boundary]

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).